Getting 'Using $this when not in object context' error when calling trait method within Laravel facade
I've encountered an issue while working with Laravel where I'm using a custom facade that includes a trait to share some methods. However, when attempting to call a method from within the facade that resides in the trait, PHP throws a "Using $this when not in object context" error. I've tried several solutions but haven't been able to resolve this problem.
This is custom facade
class PersonService
{
   use BaseService
   public function list()
   {
     return $this->resetPage();
   }
}

This is trait
protected function resetPage()
{
    return [
        'total'=>1,
        'current_page'=>1,
        'perpage'=>1,
        'data'=>[]
    ];
}

This is Controller
public function index(Request $request): JsonResponse
{
       
    $result = PersonService::list();

    return $this->success();
}

This is error

Using $this when not in object context

When I changed it to ' return self::resetPage();' it worked

You are calling a non-static method list() in a static way. Static methods do not have access to a $this variable since there is no class instantiated.
What you probably want is something like this:
public function index(Request $request): JsonResponse
{
    $personService = new PersonService();
    $result = $personService->list();
    return $this->success();
}



Thank you for your answer. I want to use Facade to call it, like this PersonService::list(). I haven't looked at the source code yet, but Facade is just calling it like a static method, but it's not actually a static method called.

If you need Facade - than make Facade. This is not Facade at all.

Sorry, I've been researching this for the past few days, and finally I found that it works when I use PersonService;; but I'm confused because this is not the actual implementation of the class of use, but theclass PersonService extends PersonServiceFacade:\ PersonService Source:.../_ide_helper Because this is a phpstorm generated auxiliary file, if I am not using phpstorm, how should I use this class?
